# How to replace with updated value in between string using C++?

Tags: c++, string, replace, blackberry-10

I'm trying to replace the string with updated value. For the first time its replacing with the updated value but after that its not updating..

This is my String :

```
 QString   JAVASCRIPT =
                     "<script>var PAGE_ID=__PAGE_ID__; var SCROLL_PERCENTAGE=__SCROLL_PERCENTAGE__;</script>"+
                      "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"scripts/quiz_objects.js\"></script>"+
                          "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"scripts/swipe.js\"></script>"+
                          "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"scripts/NativeBridge.js\"></script>"+
                          "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"scripts/native_base.js\"></script>"+
                          "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"scripts/native_device.js\"></script>"+
                          "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"js/mobi.js\"></script>";
```

I want the replace the `"PAGE_ID"` value with updated value.

```
qDebug() << "currentPageInstanceeeeeeeeId" << currentPageInstanceId;
qDebug() << "javaaaaaaaaa" << JAVASCRIPT;
JAVASCRIPT.replace(__PAGE_ID__," " + currentPageInstanceId);
```

I'm getting the updated value in `currentPageInstanceId`. Here i'm replace the `__PAGE_ID__` with `currentPageInstanceId` that's why its replaced for the first time. Now i want to replace the value between "PAGE_ID=" and ";". How can i replace. I tried like this.

```
qDebug() << "currentPageInstanceeeeeeeeId" << currentPageInstanceId;
    qDebug() << "javaaaaaaaaa" << JAVASCRIPT;
    Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = Qt::CaseSensitive;
    script = JAVASCRIPT.indexOf("PAGE_ID=",cs);
    script1 = JAVASCRIPT.lastIndexOf(";", cs);
    JAVASCRIPT.replace(script+""+ script1," " + currentPageInstanceId);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I've never used `Qstring` neither do I have access to a machine with QT rightnow. I tried though to rework your problem in Standard C++ and I think it works, check the code at http://ideone.com/QefV3C. Hope that helps :-)

Comment: @40two Thanks for your reply :) but when i'm trying this code i'm getting errors like "'pos','offset' and 'delim_idx' does not name a type".

Comment: Your compiler doesn't support C++11 change the keyword `auto` to `std::size_t`.

Comment: @40two i changed auto to std::size_t those errors are cleared but now i'm getting another error as "string does not name a type".. i delcared "string JAVASCRIPT;" in header file ... or if declared like "QString  JAVASCRIPT;" i'm getting like "'class QString' has no member named 'find'".

Comment: include string header (i.e., put in the preamble `#include <string>`).

Comment: yes i included this but still getting the same.. "string does not name a type"

Comment: replace with `std::string` maybe it needs name-space qualifier.

Comment: I mean declare `std::string JAVASCRIPT;` and not `string JAVASCRIPT`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52311/discussion-between-lucky-and-40two)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to update the value of `__PAGE_ID__` (and presumably `__SCROLL_PERCENTAGE__`) several times I would approach it this way:

Set your JAVASCRIPT value to this:

```
QString   JAVASCRIPT =
                 "<script>var PAGE_ID=%1; var SCROLL_PERCENTAGE=%2;</script>"+
                  "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"scripts/quiz_objects.js\"></script>"+
                      "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"scripts/swipe.js\"></script>"+
                      "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"scripts/NativeBridge.js\"></script>"+
                      "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"scripts/native_base.js\"></script>"+
                      "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"scripts/native_device.js\"></script>"+
                      "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"js/mobi.js\"></script>";
```

Then when you want to set the values use the arg method:

```
QString script = JAVASCRIPT.arg(currentPageInstanceId).arg(currentScrollPercentage);
```

Then use script.

Comment: then how can i replace with this arg(currentPageInstanceId) in JAVASCRIPT.

Comment: Each time you want a new script value you call the arg method again. The value of JAVASCRIPT will not change.